# como mostrar la fecha en ajax y php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo una duda cuando recargo la pagina quiero mandar las fechas en ajax pero como puedo mandar la fecha y mostrarlo en php
he intentado lo siguiente

codigo ajax:
coloco las fechas

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    // obtener la fecha de hoy en formato `MM/DD/YYYY`
    let date = new Date();
    let date1 = date.getFullYear() + '-' + String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0').val();
    console.log(date1);

    let date2 = date.getFullYear() + '-' + String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0').val();
    console.log(date2);

    url = base_url + "Home/index";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'date1': date1, 'date2': date2 },
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

cuando hago un post en php y un var_dump las fechas me muestra como resultado NULL, NULL hago el vard_dump para ver si me manda las fechas

PHP:

```
$fecha_inicial = $_POST['date1'];
$fecha_final = $_POST['date2']; 

vard_dump ($fecha_inicial,$fecha_final);
```

Comment: ¿ya has depurado bien tu javascript?  ¿no has mirado los errores de consola que aparecen al ejecutarlo tal cual?  Intentas usar el método val() en algo que no es de jquery por lo que parece, y no entiendo que querias conseguir con eso tampoco.  Si lo quitas aparece bien el número del dia, no se si por ahi van los tiros.

Comment: @masterguru hola gracias por responder pues tuve error al colocar el val como lo habías comentado y ahorita lo elimine y no me muestra ningún error y cuando solo hago un console.log al date1 y date2 me muestra las fechas pero cuando coloco el ajax ya no me muestra se queda en blanco

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con las modificaciones que has hecho para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Para ello pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta y corrige lo que hayas hecho para tomarlo como punto de partida para ayudarte, gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, no es `vard_dump` sino `var_dump` (supongo que lo tienes bien en tu código real, pero aquí lo has puesto mal... corrígelo tambien)

Comment: Y por cierto, arreglando esas dos cosas (el val() y el vard_dump) y probándolo en local a mi me funciona bien... si a ti sigue sin funcionarte mira que no sea el base_url que no está definido o bien la ruta la tengas mal

Comment: @masterguru si es la direccion en la que estoy mandando ahi me marca el error

Comment: A ver, tu código funciona... lo que pienso es que quizás no lo sabes ver... debes abrir el inspector de objetos (F12 en tu navegador), irte a la pestaña Red (o algo asi), seleccionar la linea del POST que veas alli e irte a la pestaña "respuesta" para que veas el resultado del var_dump (eso en firefox, en chrome ni idea)... a mi me devuelve esto: `string(10) "2022-11-25" string(10) "2022-11-25"`

Comment: o tambien lo puedes ver en la consola seleccionando el POST y la pestaña respuesta (y en modo raw, sino te aparece en HTML y aparece vacio)

Comment: @masterguru gracias si funciona y obtengo este resutado lo hice tal como me dijo 
 "date1": "2022-11-24",
 "date2": "2022-11-24"

Comment: Si quieres quitar verbosidad a tu código, puedes hacer esto para obtener la fecha: `let date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];` Ver [la doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) para más detalles.